# Regular Expression Fails

Tags: javascript, regex

Anyone help?  When I run this I get " invalid quantifier ?<=href= "

```
var aHrefMatch = new RegExp("(?<=href\=")[^]+?(?=")"); 
var matchedLink = mystring.match(aHrefMatch);
```

But I know the regular expression is valid.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Javascript does not support lookbehind assertions. It only supports lookahead ones. The error is produced because it assumes the ? is a quantifier for 0 or 1, but there is no element to quantify at the beginning of a subpattern (started by that `(` opening parenthesis)

Also, your string seems to be missing a few backslashes, as the double quotes are not escaped there. It should produce a syntax error.

Perhaps this code could help you do what you are trying to achieve:

```
var match = mystring.match(/href=\"([^\"]*)\"/);
var matchedLink = match[1];
```

Comment: +1 for the only answer to point out *both* problems: lookbehinds and unescaped quotes.

Comment: Yep, have just read another article stating that js does not support lookbehind assertions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the double quotes in the regular expression with the standard backslash:

```
var aHrefMatch = new RegExp("(?<=href\=\")[^]+?(?=\")");
```

...or you could just use single quotes to specify the string:

```
var aHrefMatch = new RegExp('(?<=href\=")[^]+?(?=")');
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean to escape the quote after the = sign and after the look ahead ?=.
Also if you are just trying to match the href="some text" , then you really don't need look behind and look ahead constructs. The following should do just fine

```
href=\"[^"]+\"
```

If you are trying to match something else, please elaborate. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't really know what you want to do. But if you want to get the link.

```
var aHrefMatch = new RegExp(/(href\=\")([\w\-\/]+)?(\")/); 
var matchedLink = mystring.match(aHrefMatch)[2];
```

Comment: Yeah I need to get the href of the anchor elements in a string. Fredrik your code seems closest but when I run it I get:-

illegal character
var aHrefMatch = new RegExp(href=\"[^"]+\"); \n

Comment: Make sure that you remove all whitespace, sounds like some illegal char made it it's why in to you copy/paste.

If not please paste what mystring looks like.

Comment: The RegExp constructor takes a string as its first argument.  @Meander365, change the `/` at the beginning and end to `"`.  Or just use a regex literal, as @Rithiur suggested.